# Loading data from SQL Server into C# application

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have some problem accessing my data from a SQL Server database via C# application. I have a small project to make and I can't go further because my data is loading in. I try to load it in a `DataGridView`.

Here are some code examples:

```
public List<Country> GetCountryList()
{
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Orszag", error = string.Empty;
        SqlDataReader rdr = ExecuteReader(query, ref error);

        List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();
        if (error == "OK")
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Country item = new Country();
                item.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);
                item.CountryName = rdr[1].ToString();
                countryList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        CloseDataReader(rdr);

        return countryList;
    }
```

This is where I put my data in a list

```
private void FillDgvGames()
{
        dgvGames.Rows.Clear();
        List<Country> CountryList = m_Country.GetCountryList();

        foreach (Country item in CountryList)
        {
            dgvGames.Rows.Add(item.CountryId,item.CountryName);
        }
}
```

And this is where I retrieve it ...  I have to make the same thing with 8 more tables but this is the simplest and I thought it's easier this way.... if someone can help me I'd appreciate it ...

PS:

This is the execute reader

```
protected SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string query, ref string errorMessage)
{
        try
        {
            OpenConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, m_Connection);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            errorMessage = "OK";
            return rdr;
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            errorMessage = e.Message;
            CloseConnection();
            return null;
        }
}
```

And this is the connection string

```
protected string m_ConnectionString = "Data Source=SpD-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

Comment: I don't understand the actual issue. _" i can't go further beacause my data is loading in"_ What does that mean?

Comment: You don't say what exception or other unexpected behaviour this causes.

Comment: the problem is that my data grid view is blank ..... my data doesn't appear ....

Comment: I'm guessing but I think that should have been written as: "beacause my data is **NOT** loading in."

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?  I don't see a connection in there anywhere for the SqlDataReader to get its data from.

Comment: yeah ... sorry i have to do it for tomorrow so i'm a bit in a hurry ... sorry for that ...

Comment: i edited my post ... ia dded the connection string and execute reader method ..

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside the while and debug, do you ever hit the breakpoint. This would prove that you are at least getting some records back.

Comment: i think it doesn't go in the while ... i wrote something on the console in the while but nothing happened ....

Comment: anyone some help? ......

Comment: What kind of application is this? ASP.NET? Winforms? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: it's C# ... and the database in Sql

Comment: where is this m_Connection come from?

Comment: what do you have in `openconnection()`?

Comment: ` m_Connection = new SqlConnection(m_ConnectionString);`

Comment: `protected bool OpenConnection()
        {
            // Open the Connection when the state is not already open.
            if (Connected != true)
            {
                try
                {
                    CreateConnection();
                    m_Connection.Open();
                    Connected = true;
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }`

Comment: debug the code and tell me what you are getting in `error` variable from ExecuteReader method.

Comment: it returns with "OK" so not that's the problem ... i think it's only when i want to put a row in the DGV that's when something happens ... it think .... but i'm not sure ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the data source of your DataGridView?

```
dgvGames.DataSource = CountryList;
```